# How to configure start date parameter to pass to the query this 2014-08-12 200:00:00.000 format

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, parameter-passing

I've tried this:
=CDate(Format(DateAdd("yyyy",-1,Today), "yyyy-MM-dd" & " 00:00:01"))

the result is: 8/12/2013 12:00:01 AM, which is fine in the display of the report but

I need it to pass this to the query: 2014-08-12 00:00:01.000

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish is SQL with that timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your data may already have the datetime with milliseconds. If it does then you need to set the format of the text box with "MMMM-dd-yy h:mm:ss.fff".

refer to .. [Format option for milliseconds](http://skamie.wordpress.com/2012/05/21/ssrs-format-option-for-milliseconds/)

or google.. ssrs milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Format((DateAdd("yyyy",-1,Today),"YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.fff")

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=IIf(FORMAT(CDate(IIf(CSTR(Fields!EMP_REVISED_END_DATE.Value)="","1900-01-01",Fields!EMP_REVISED_END_DATE.Value)),"dd-MMM-yyyy")="01-Jan-1900","",
FORMAT(CDate(IIf(CSTR(Fields!EMP_REVISED_END_DATE.Value)="","1900-01-01",Fields!EMP_REVISED_END_DATE.Value)),"dd-MMM-yyyy"))
```